# struggling with unique key props while creating multiple dynamically rendered TextInputs

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm having a problem understanding how to set the keys for my TextInputs. I have a list of 3 dynamically rendered TextInputs. I'm using the useState hook. I can get them to render on the screen by creating a onPress Handler, enter text in them and delete them.

My problem is that I keep getting a warning in my console that: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Where I'm setting the state of each text input I have the key set to an empty string and the same where I add the list to the screen. I have tried entering in different values for the keys but still get the same warning in the console.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Could anyone offer some suggestions on how I can make sure that the keys I set will be unique and be able to access them later when I need to use the values of the text inputs?

I will post my code below in case anyone can easily see where I'm going wrong.

```
const Test = () => {
  const [sets, setSets] = useState([{ key: "", value: "" }]);
  const [weights, setWeights] = useState([{ key: "", value: "" }]);
  const [reps, setReps] = useState([{ key: "", value: "" }]);

  ///////////////////////Add ///////////////////////////////
  const addSetsHandler = () => {
    const _sets = [...sets];
    _sets.push({ key: "", value: "" });
    setSets(_sets);
  };

  const addWeightsHandler = () => {
    const _weights = [...weights];
    _weights.push({ key: "", value: "" });
    setWeights(_weights);
  };

  const addRepsHandler = () => {
    const _reps = [...reps];
    _reps.push({ key: "", value: "" });
    setReps(_reps);
  };
  //////////////////////End////////////////////////////////////

  //////////////////////Delete ////////////////////////////////
  const deleteSetsHandler = (key) => {
    const _sets = sets.filter((input, index) => index != key);
    setSets(_sets);
  };
  const deleteWeightsHandler = (key) => {
    const _weights = weights.filter((input, index) => index != key);
    setWeights(_weights);
  };
  const deleteRepsHandler = (key) => {
    const _reps = reps.filter((input, index) => index != key);
    setReps(_reps);
  };
  ////////////////////////End//////////////////////////////////

  ///////////////////////Input////////////////////////////////
  const inputSetsHandler = (text, key) => {
    const _sets = [...sets];
    _sets[key].value = text;
    _sets[key].key = key;
    setSets(_sets);
  };
  const inputWeightsHandler = (text, key) => {
    const _weights = [...weights];
    _weights[key].value = text;
    _weights[key].key = key;
    setWeights(_weights);
  };
  const inputRepsHandler = (text, key) => {
    const _reps = [...reps];
    _reps[key].value = text;
    _reps[key].key = key;
    setReps(_reps);
  };

  ///////////////////////End//////////////////////////////
```

and the return

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.inputsContainer}>
        {sets.map((sets, key) => (
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <View>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder={"Enter Name"}
                value={sets.value}
                onChangeText={(text) => inputSetsHandler(text, key)}
              />
            </View>

            <View>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder={"Enter Weight"}
                value={weights.value}
                onChangeText={(text) => inputWeightsHandler(text, key)}
              />
            </View>

            <View>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder={"Enter Reps"}
                value={reps.value}
                onChangeText={(text) => inputRepsHandler(text, key)}
              />
            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.delete}
              onPress={() => {
                deleteSetsHandler(key),
                  deleteWeightsHandler(key),
                  deleteRepsHandler(key);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "red", fontSize: 13 }}>Delete</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <Button
        title="Add"
        onPress={() => {
          addSetsHandler(), addWeightsHandler(), addRepsHandler();
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Try ```{sets.map((sets, key) => (<View style={styles.inputContainer} key={key}>```

Comment: that appears to have solved the problem thank you

Comment: Cool, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each component returns by the `map` needs an explicit `key` attribute. If you want to use the array index `key`, try this:

```js
        {sets.map((sets, key) => (
          <View style={styles.inputContainer} key={key}>
```